# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Google Maps library

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-studio

Good afternoon.

I have a project in which I use the Google Maps library. The project is realized with Eclipse and I never had any problems. Two weeks ago I installed the Android Studio and migrated my project. Since then, when I make the call to the map I get an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError". At compile time everything goes perfectly but when I run it on the phone is when the error arises.

Thank you.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new Android Application Project and copy the folders required from your previous project and run the application.

I too was facing a similar issue on Eclipse itself, and received Trgaet InvocationException and NoClassDefFoundError, for the same code which was correctly working for weeks.

Hope it works, although it is not a permanent solution.